# Threading does not work when deploying to another server

Tags: multithreading, dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a web page where users can upload a file which contains data that are inserted into the Lead table in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011.

The weird thing now is that when I deploy to our test environment the application runs fine seemingly but absolutely no rows are imported. In my dev environment it works just fine.

After a while when trying to find the error I created a setting that runs the application without using threading (Thread.Run basically) and then it inserts all the Leads. If I switch back to using threads it inserts no leads at all although I get no application errors.

When using SQL Server Profiler I can see in dev (where it works with threading) that all of the insert statements run. When profiling in test environment no insert statements at all are run.

I sort of get the feeling that there is some server issue or setting that is causing this behaviour but when googling I don't really get any results that have helped me.

I was sort of hoping that someone recognizes this problem. I haven't got much experience in using threading so maybe this is some road bump that I need to go over.

I cannot show my code completely but this is basically how I start the threads:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfThreads; i++)
    {
      MultipleRequestObject mpObject = new MultipleRequestObject() { insertType = insertType, listOfEntities = leadsForInsertionOrUpdate[i].ToList<Entity>() };
      Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
      {
        insertErrors.AddRange(leadBusinessLogic.SaveToCRMMultipleRequest(mpObject));           
      });

      thread.Start();
      activeThreads.Add(thread);
    }

    // Wait for threads to complete
    foreach (Thread t in activeThreads)
      t.Join();
```

I initialize my crm connection like this (it reads the connectionstring from web.config -> connectionstrings)

```
public CrmConnection connection { get; set; }
private IOrganizationService service { get; set; }
public CrmContext crmContext { get; set; }

public CrmGateway()
{
  connection = new CrmConnection("Crm");
  service = (IOrganizationService)new OrganizationService(connection);
  crmContext = new CrmContext(service);
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the connection to the server?

Comment: I updated my post with the connection settings. It uses the same exakt way to connect regardless of wheter I use threading or not. It works with threading when I run the webpage from my local computer (which points towards the dev-server when inserting), it works if I deploy to the dev-server but only works without threading on the sys-server.

Comment: Are you creating a CRM connection per thread?